# What Android Tablet Currently Supports Accessory Mode for ADK Development

Tags: android, tablet, adk

Unfortunately, the Samsung Galaxy Tab 10.1 I received at Google IO does not support accessory mode (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6355031/how-can-i-get-the-adk-demokit-example-working-on-a-google-i-o-galaxy-tab-10-1).  Which Android tablet currently does?  I spoke with one of the Google engineer's at the conference who was running the DemoKit app on a tablet, but I didn't catch which one he was using, and whether that device was rooted or not.  Is there a tablet out there running Honeycomb 3.1 that installs/runs the DemoKit app right out of the box without having to be rooted?

Answer (score 0):

The adk stuff runs great on the Xoom, now on Android 3.2.  I've been using both ADK accessory mode and USB host mode, and I haven't rooted it.  The demoKit works great, although the Arduino-side can be a little tricky (usb host shield libraries) without an official ADK board.

Answer (score 0):

I got the simple demo's working on the asus eee TF101, android version 3.2.1
I do have a bit of weir behavior that the android app wants to force quit a few times and the connection to the adk is not made immediately (can't choose to have the accessory connect to the app from a list the tablet pops up), but after a few times back and forth between the app and the home screen (through several 'force quit' dialog boxes), I do get the option to connect the accessory (ADK board) to be connected to the example app and then it all works as wanted.
I do have the same behavior on a Nexus One phone, so I'm guessing there may be something not quite right in my SDK setup.

Answer (score 0):

Samsung Galaxy 10.1 Tab with updated Android 3.2 works fine with Google ADK board. I could see all sensors working fine. My issue is to get the tab work with Arduino Mega ADK.