# Is it possible to get the Android ADK working on an ASUS Eee Pad Transformer running 3.1?

Tags: android, transformer-model, adk

I am running the [ADK](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/usb/adk.html) demo app tweaked for Android 3.1, using the ASUS Eee Pad Transformer tablet and an ADK board, built as described in *[Get Started With Android ADK (LINUX)](http://www.googleadk.com/?page_id=17)*.

I seem to be having the same symptoms as described in Stack Overflow question *[How can I get the ADK DemoKit example working on a Google I/O Galaxy Tab 10.1?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6355031)*.  It could be the transformer does not support the ADK yet (as per the Galaxy tab), but is it possible to get the Transformer working somehow?

Answer (score 0):

With the changes in the other question I get a compiled version of the demo app and can run the app but when I connect the tablet to the shield nothings happens, it's like the cable which comes with the tablet isn't valid for use with that.

Answer (score 0):

I emailed Asus technical support about whether or not the Transformer supports the ADK. This is the response I got:

Dear Valued Customer,

Thank you for contacting ASUS Customer Service. The USB ports on TF101 system only supports the external storage devices like flash drive or HDD with USB cable, File system needs to be FAT/FAT32/NTFS. CD/DVD ROM drivers are currently not supported. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Thank you,

Jason

ASUS Customer Service.