# Getting the Arduino ADK DemoKit example to work on a 3.1 Toshiba Thrive (AT-100)

Tags: android, arduino, adk

I've been having some trouble getting my Arduino ADK to work with my Toshiba Thrive (or AT-100 in EU). It's running 3.1, but I'm aware in the US there has been an update recently to 3.2. Unfortunately the 3.2 update isn't available in the EU yet. I'm wondering if there is anyone who has successfully got this working on 3.1 or 3.2?

So here's the deal. I've used the API level 12 libraries to suit the 3.1 build, but had to manually edit the AndroidManinfest.xml file so the minSDKversion and the targetSDKversion both read 12, as was mentioned by [John regarding the Samsung Galaxy Tab problems.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6355031/how-can-i-get-the-adk-demokit-example-working-on-a-google-i-o-galaxy-tab-10-1)

However, unlike john's issues, I've been able to get the DemoKit app to compile and install fine, except for 8 warnings regarding the color wheel LED controller values not being used.

The screen even loads up on the Toshiba asking me to attach the ADK, but when I do it does nothing. I've tried resetting and unplugging and re-uploading the firmware to the ADK board.

Like John, I've also tried changing the Accessory API's from com.android.future.usb to android.hardware.usb along with the manifest file, but now it doesn't even install, giving the error message INSTALL_FAILED_MISSING_SHARED_LIBRARY, with Logcat saying W/dalvikvm(18874): Refusing to reopen boot DEX 'system/framework/pm.jar

I feel like I'm so close but there is just one small thing wrong. Can anyone shed any light on this?

Comment: ok, the reason changing the accessory API didn't work was because I kept the new line of code in the manifest file as a library rather than a feature. It compiles now, but it is still not connecting to the ADK. An interesting point that was made by dalepl on thriveforums.org is that the Thrive has two USB ports - One a micro USB for computer connection and debugging, and one a full size USBa port. But even connecting that one up to the board it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

There possibly is an answer here:

http://www.thriveforums.org/forum/toshiba-thrive-development/5410-arduino-adk-demokit-application-3-1-thrive-100-a.html#post58900

Havent tried it out myself though - will do it if i don't find any other option.

Comment: Links are not answers.  When that link goes dead, your answer becomes useless.  Can you summarize the relevant content from the remote site?